# Cassandra CQL driver implementation

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, drivers, nosql

I have used Cassandra CQL driver to implement some module. I know CQL driver works on port 9042.My module is working fine on port 9042 for cassandra servers(tried both local and remote). However due to some constraints on the data center port 9042 is not open for Cassandra. I need to make my application work on this data center.

Can we use the same code in some way with port 9160? I know 9160 is the thrift port and used for many other drivers for Cassandra. I was just wondering if there is any hack possible to make CQL driver work on 9160 or modify the code as little as possible to make it work on 9160.

Currently when I try to use the same code with port 9160 it gives the following error

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s)  tried for query failed (tried: xx.yy.zz.aa        (com.datastax.driver.core.ConnectionException:  [xx.yy.zz.aa :9160] Unexpected   error during   transport initialization 
(com.datastax.driver.core.ConnectionException:   [xx.yy.zz.aa :9160] Operation timed out)),         xx.yy.zz.aa :9160
```

When I try to telnet 9160 port

```
telnet xx.yy.zz.aa 9160
Trying xx.yy.zz.aa...
Connected to xx.yy.zz.aa.
Escape character is '^]'.
xyzaaaa
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Looking for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the CQL interface available on port 9160 by changing the [native_transport_port](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__native_transport_port) from 9042 to 9160 in cassandra.yaml on your cassandra server(s).  You will also need to change [rpc_port](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__rpc_port) to something other than 9160.

In the datastax java-driver you can configure the port to use in Cluster.Builder by using the [withPort](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.Builder.html#withPort(int)) method.

Comment: Thanks Andy for the response. I agree that if we make this change my application will start working on 9160 port. But the problem is if we change the rpc_port from 9160 to some other port then existing applications which are already deployed and are using older cassandra drivers will break as there port will change.
Any other suggestion?

Comment: Unfortunately you are going to need two separate ports, one for thrift, one for the native transport (CQL), they cannot be shared.   You can do CQL over Thrift, but most drivers do not support this and you also lose the benefits for CQL (i.e., multiple requests per connection) when doing it over thrift.